# Azure B2C SignUp Userflow shows that password has expired

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm deploying local Azure B2C users using code.

```
var graphUser = new User
{
    DisplayName = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}",
    GivenName = user.FirstName,
    Surname = user.LastName,
    // PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword",
    Identities = new[]
    {
        new ObjectIdentity { SignInType = "emailAddress", Issuer = _tenantId, IssuerAssignedId = user.Email }
    },
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile { Password = "Password123!", ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true }
};
User createdUser = await _graphServiceClient.Users
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(graphUser);
```

When user is trying to signin using Sign up and sign in userflow he receives information that password has expired. Resetting the password in Azure B2C does not help. User still receives information that password has expired. I tried different options in `PasswordPolicies`. Not set at all, set to `DisablePasswordExpiration` and set to `DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword` but no change.

What's interesting is tha when I'm using Sign in user flow accounts provisioned with code above are able to log in.

Comment: Check you didn’t set forceChangePassword to true on this user. It must be set to false. Password policy must be set to DisablePasswordExpiration. Only the old deprecated sign in flow supports forceChangePassword True. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions

Comment: Yes it was set in code above. Once I switched it to false it works. One note. This flag is bool? but you can't leave it as null, you must set it to false to be able to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Azure Ad B2C is showing the user's password is expired is because you have set ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true.

This needs to be set to false.

Comment: No, it's not it. I just tested it.

Comment: I checked again but this time I set this flag to `false` instead of not setting it to `true`. It's bool? so I thought by default it will work as `false` but my tests show it is treated as `true`. With flag set to `false` I'm able to log in.

Answer (score 1):

By default force password reset is not available.

So if you always wants to for password change, here is the MS doc to configure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/force-password-reset?pivots=b2c-user-flow

For conditional logic you need to customize the flow

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon